# How to find the length of an LPCSTR

Tags: c++, lpcstr

I'm trying to convert an LPCSTR to an integer using atoi(), and to verify that the conversion occurred successfully I want to count the number of digits in the integer it produced and the original LPCSTR (it should contain nothing but integers)

I'm having a hard time finding a good way to calculate the length of the LPCSTR.  So far the only way seems to be just counting until I get to a '/0'

Any suggestions for a better method?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isn't that what strlen does?

Comment: Doh! Sorry guys, brain fart.  Must have had some kind of a mental block to not remember this one and never see it on any of my searches

Comment: @sean as this answer was incorrectly accepted, can you updated it and credit MrD below?

Answer (score 26):

To find the length (in this case, the number of digits) of an `LPCTSTR`, you should be using `lstrlen()` and not `strlen()`.  Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This should have been accepted ;) For learners: If unicode is used(`#ifdef UNICODE`), lstrlen is lstrlenW, `int lstrlenW([in] LPCWSTR lpString);` and LPCTSTR is `typedef LPCWSTR PCTSTR, LPCTSTR;` In short: LPCTSTR is `const wchar_t*` if unicode, else `const char*`.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) and use the `endptr` returned to check if it's the end of the string (0 byte).

Counting will not necessarily be accurate. "00" will result in 0, but 0 has one digit and the original string has length 2.

Answer (score 5):

The [strlen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28VS.71%29.aspx) function is what you're looking for.

Sample usage:

```
size_t len = strlen( szNumber );
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

That's how you find the length of a c-string.  You could use `strlen`, but it still has to go down the whole string and count the number of characters before a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

Talk about producing more heat than light... :) Stop using 'atoi' and that will solve most of your problems. 'atoi' is a dead function with no practical value. The proper way to convert a string representation to a number is functions from 'strto...' group ('strtol', 'strtoul' etc.). These functions will return enough information back to you to determine right away whether a conversion error occured or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
LPCSTR lpText = "test";
long lTextLen = CString(lpText).GetLength();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do things a bit differently -- initialize a stringstream with the input, read an int, then check whether the stream is empty:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

typedef char const *LPCSTR;

template <class T>
bool check_read(LPCSTR input, T &val) { 
    std::istringstream reader(input);

    reader >> val;
    char ch;
    if (reader >> ch) {
        std::cerr << "\nUnconverted character: " << ch << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() { 
    LPCSTR inputs[] = {"12345", "54321a"};
    int a;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        check_read(inputs[i], a);
        std::cout << "Converted: " << a << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another reasonable possibility would be strtol or one of its cousins. These return a pointer to the first un-converted character (if any), so they tell you fairly directly what was and wasn't converted. They're faster but generally less flexible than streams -- for example, if you want to read a floating point number, the check_read above will work as-is, but something using strtol would need to be rewritten.

As yet one more possibility, you might consider Boost lexical_cast (which is packaged a little differently, but pretty similar to the code above).

Answer (score 0):

Since `LPCSTR` is just `const char*` (after de-macroing), `strlen` will be fine.

However if you're after a windows function explicitly defined to correspond with `LPCSTR` input, then you could use `lstrlenA`. I seriously doubt there's any practical difference calling this and calling `strlen` though.